# How to create a Formtastic input consisting of two parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I want to create a GeographyInput, which will have a textfield for latitude and a textfield for longitude. The result must be pieced together in the form of `"POINT (#{longitude}, #{latitude})"` (for RGeo) before saving to database.

Is there a way to do this? I looked at the documentation and all Formtastic input modifications seem to be cosmetic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Formtastic does not have `multi_input` support out of the box.

You may write a wrapper input, but I would rather suggest to just have to inputs `geo_long` and `geo_lat` and just connect these two inside your controller where you accept the params.

Then, pass these values on to your model. Or even better, have two `attr_accessor` inside your model to store both values independently.